# Angularjs: Onchange event when the user hits enter

Tags: html, angularjs, events, html-table, updates

I have a HTML table in which one of the column is editable

```
<td ng-model="my.grade">
   <div contenteditable>
  {{list.grade}}
   </div>
</td>
```

I have an angular function `getInformation` which does some calculation and connects to back end and then 
makes the table. My goal is that when the user changes the value of above column and hits the enter I want to update the table and basically re-run the function `getInformation`.
I read that I should `ng-model` and `ng-change` but how should I update the table value on the enter?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
<td ng-model="row.grade" 
    contenteditable ng-keypress='keyPressed($event)'></td>
```

So, `ng-model` and `contenteditable` must be on the same element.
Also, if you specify `ng-model` on a element, **all** of its content will be replaced by the value from a model. So it should be empty.

And

```
$scope.keyPressed = function (e){
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);

    if(code == 13) { // 'Enter' keycode
      $scope.getInformation(); // your function here or some other code
      e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Here is working Plunkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/sHHlqF

Why do you use `contenteditable`? Maybe you could use just `<input ng-model...>`?